# No me carga PostgreSQL al momento de abrirlo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-12

Mi problema con el PostgreSQL es que, al momento de abrirlo y ejecutarlo se queda la pantalla en blanco y con unas letras que dicen: *Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4...* . Desde el momento que estoy escribiendo este mensaje lleva ya 3 horas y no hace nada mas. E buscado por foros y videos, pero ninguno me da una respuesta ni solución. Verifique el puerto y el xampp lo tengo activado solo la opción de *Apache*. De resto nada más. En verdad que no se si debo de dejarlo mas tiempo cargando o es normal que se tarde tanto en abrir. Se acepta cualquier recomendación o ayuda. Muchas gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Has instalado PostgreSQL? ¿Has verificado que el servicio esté en ejecución? ¿Viste si el puerto 5432 está abierto y/o siendo usado por otro servicio?

Comment: Si. Lo instale junto a sus dependencias. Como puedo saber si el servicio esta en ejecución? Al igual que saber, si el puerto esta ocupado?

Comment: Inicio, ejecutar, `services.msc` ahí busca y encuentra a `PostgreSQL`, el status te dirá.  Ahora, para ver si el puerto está en uso: inicio, ejecutar, `netstat -a`, busca y encuentra si hay `0.0.0.0:5432` ó `127.0.0.1:5432`

Comment: Okey acabo de verificar y el postgre esta en ejecución. Ahora, en el apartado del puerto. Sale algo que dice: TCP    0.0.0.0:5040      (Aqui pone uno cosa de desktop y numero y letras raros)     LISTENING

Comment: Quizás configuraste que el puerto sea diferente del que viene by default. Revisa a qué puerto se comunica.

Comment: Que raro. Viendo un video me dijo que no moviera nada de eso, y fue lo que hice. De todos modos uno nunca sabe. Como puedo ver en que puerto lo instale? Si no me deja entrar a la aplicación? En que documento o apartado?

Comment: utiliza el programa Dbeaver y al momento de conectar con el postgres, utiliza el puerto que dices, ese 5040 y si conecta, es porque sí era. Me parece muy raro que hayas instalado todo by default y que el puerto se haya cambiado.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me paso lo mismo.

> Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4...

La solución fue que instale la version de [postgresql](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) 15.3  pero sin el pgadmin, luego me dirigi a la página para instalar [pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/).

Comment: Si, literalmente eso fue lo que hice. Y me funciono, gracias por su recomendación y espero que a alguien que tenga este mismo problema lo logre solucionar

Answer (score 0):

me paso lo mismo "Cargando PGAdmin 4 v7.4. Ando atorada aqui y ya vi que si se esta ejecutando el programa y también aparece el puerto 0.0.0.5432 listening...y ahora que significa eso. Se puede arreglar desde aqui?

la otra opción es desinstalar todo, borrar todos los registros y isntalar sin PG admin ok

Comment: Hola GUADALUPE, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.